# Flutter login screen go top when using keyborad

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello i create a login screen but when i check on input inputfield the textbox go to top and big space between keyboard and inputfield i also use singlechildscrollview but its not working please help

```
class LoginView extends StatelessWidget {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<LoginViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModel: LoginViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 150,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.jpg'),
                ),
                InputField(
                  placeholder: 'Email',
                  controller: emailController,
                ),
                verticalSpaceSmall,
                InputField(
                  placeholder: 'Password',
                  password: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                ),
                verticalSpaceMedium,
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    BusyButton(
                      title: 'Login',
                      busy: model.busy,
                      onPressed: () {
                        model.login(
                          email: emailController.text,
                          password: passwordController.text,
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**Login screen using keyboard**
[image: Login screen using keyboard]

**Login screen when don't use keyboard**
[image: Login screen when don't use keyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Scaffold` with this property in your code.

`resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false`,